# MS SQL Change expiry date when inserting value with same name

Tags: sql-server, date, triggers, match

I have a question relating to trigger. I have a table (FoodPrice) with different columns like a start date and an expiry date. 
Let's consider that I would like to add a price that could expire like a sale, I would like (ON INSERT) to set the ExpiryDate of the previous value to the current date:

Initial table

```
Food      Value         StartDate     ExpiryDate
------    ----------    ----------    ----------
Carrot    25.5          24/12/2013    NULL
Apple     44.9          5/1/2014      NULL
Squash    25.6          12/3/2013     NULL
```

New table with inserted rows:

```
Food      Value         StartDate     ExpiryDate
------    ----------    ----------    ----------
Carrot    25.5          24/12/2013    28/4/2014
Apple     44.9          5/1/2014      NULL
Squash    25.6          12/3/2013     28/4/2014
Carrot    24            28/4/2014     NULL
Squash    22            28/4/2014     NULL
```

Dupplicate values for Food column is not a big deal but is it possible to create a trigger to solve this problem ? Thank you !

Comment: What exactly is the previous value? By date? And also, which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry my explanation wasn't clear. By 'previous' I meant the value of ExpiryDate before a new insert. 
For example, in the new table, the 'previous' row for Carrot is the one where Value is 25.5. And the new Value for Carrot is 24.
The version is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
-- the table and sample data
create table FoodPrice (
    Food varchar(10),     
    Value decimal(5,2),        
    StartDate date,    
    ExpiryDate date
);
go

insert FoodPrice values
('Carrot',    20,          '20131124' ,   '20131224'),
('Apple' ,    40,          '20140101' ,   '20140105'),
('Squash',    25,          '20130301' ,   '20130312'),
('Carrot',    25.5,        '20131224' ,   NULL),
('Apple' ,    44.9,        '20140105' ,   NULL),
('Squash',    25.6,        '20130312' ,   NULL)
go

-- the trigger
create trigger trFoodPrice_insert
on FoodPrice
after insert
as

;with x as (
    select fp.food, fp.startdate as fp_startdate, fp.expirydate as fp_expirydate, 
        ins.startdate as ins_startdate, ins.expirydate as ins_expirydate,
        row_number() over(partition by fp.food order by fp.startdate) as rn
    from ins 
    inner join foodprice fp on ins.food=fp.food 
        and fp.startdate < ins.startdate
        and fp.expirydate is null
),
y as (
    select *
    from x
    where rn = 1
)
--select * from y
update y
set fp_expirydate = ins_startdate
go

-- let's test it
insert foodprice values 
('Carrot', 24, '20140428', null),
('Squash', 22, '20140428', null)
go

select * from 
foodprice
order by food, startdate
```

As always, I'm a big fan of first testing the select before the actual update, hence the CTE.

Comment: It works like a charm ! The only problem was I replaced 'ins' by 'inserted'. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change that. `ins` was my auxilliary table -- I always start writing/modifying a trigger by first saving `inserted` to a real table on one execution and work the queries from there.